# Binding a parameter to an ember component and handle it from the controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to create the following component in ember (templates / components / echo-hlabel-tf.hbs)

```
<div id="echo-hlabel-tf">
  <span id="tf-label">{{label}}</span>
  <span id="tf-value">
    <input type="text" value={{textValue}}
    {{action "validateRegExp" textValue regExp post on="focusOut"}} 
    {{action "showText" textValue post on="mouseUp"}} 
    />
  </span>
</div>
```

Just a textfield and a label placed in the same row . I have created the functions in the controller of the component (components / echo-hlabel-tf.js):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
actions: {
    validateRegExp(text,regExpStr){
        let regExpObj = new RegExp(regExpStr)
        if(regExpObj.test(text)){
            console.log('entry matches')
        }else{
            console.log('entry is wrong');  
        }

    },
    showText(text){
        console.log(text);
    }
}
});
```

I want to use this component from another template (template / programmers.hbs) :

```
<ul>
 {{people-list title="List of programmers" people=model}}
</ul> 
<div>
 {{echo-hlabel-tf 
    label="Textfield horizontal"
    textValue="..." 
    regExp="^([a-z0-9]{5})$"
 }}
</div>
```

The thing is that , even the actions are fired as the events trigger, the variable that represents the value of the input (textValue) always stands the same ("...") . seems that the binding between the outer template, and the components is created at the beginning, but if I put more letters in the textfield , the value of textValue remains the same and doesn't change . I would like to, as I'm adding letters to the textBox, print them with the console with the method showText, but I always print "..."

Comment: You have `on='focusOut'` in your code. Did you try  keyDown/keyUp/keyPress, that would change value after each key.

Comment: I'll give a try this afternoon . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using pure html5 `input` that does not do two way binding by itself. That is even if you type something, it is not reflected to `textValue` attribute. You can use ember's builtin `input` component as in this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/764d69c1e9ff3b3afd159d616e668e62?openFiles=templates.components.my-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs). I believe this will solve your problem.

Comment: Wow ... playing with twiddle , seems that it will solve my problems . Lately I'll check because now I'm in another environment , though . On the other hand, I didn't know 'ember twiddle' . It would be easier for everybody to present the problem this way . Thanks @alptugd for the answer , and for discovering to me ember twiddle .

Comment: twiddle is great for trials; I would highly recommend it.